# Не устанавливаются куки из node.js в браузере

Tags: node.js, cookie, express

Добрый день. Есть сервер на node.js, который посылает в post-запросе куки пользователю после успешной авторизации. Эти куки содержатся в ответе от сервера, но браузер их не устанавливает. В чем может быть проблема?
Развернуто все на localhost пока что.

Сервер:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    cookie = require('cookie');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, HEAD');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.post('/login', jsonParser, (request, response) => {
    if(!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);

    var dbHandler = mysql.createPool({
        database : config.get('db:database'),
        host     : config.get('db:host'),
        user     : config.get('db:user'),
        password : config.get('db:password'),
        insecureAuth: config.get('db:insecureAuth'),
    });
    getUser(dbHandler, request.body.username, request.body.password, function(id){
        getPlace(dbHandler, id, function(place){
            getItems(dbHandler, place['id'], place['url'], function(items){
                response.cookie('logined', true, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000*60*60*24), domain:'localhost:8000/', httpOnly: true });
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
                response.send('Ok');
            });
        });
    });
})
app.listen(config.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server is listening on', config.get('port'));
})
```

На фронте - JQuery, который через AJAX отправляет запросы. С ним все в порядке, запросы идут, но куки не ставятся.

[image: Запрос в браузере]

Comment: читайте документацию про аутентификацию и авторизацию. logined хранится на клиенской части - доверять значению нельзя, его можно изменить. Там должен идентификатор сессии с серверной части, и с сервера должны брать инфу о юзере.

Comment: Вопрос о работоспособности, а не безопасности. То, что куки ненадежны я знаю. Мне непонятно, почему браузер их не "ест".